# MYSQLI Logical ordering when using ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

How do I get order by to logically order the buyers numbers?

The query:

```
SELECT * FROM $auction_id ORDER BY buyer_num
```

Results:

```
> 1 2 23 3 32 4 5 6 62 7 8 9 10
```

What I need the results to output:

```
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 23 32 62
```

Comment: And the `buyer_num` is `varchar` datatype ?

Comment: What is the data type of `buyer_num` column?

Comment: Yes, buyer_num is VARCHAR as the "house" usually uses an "H" as its Identifier during sales. and you often have "no sales" which are designated with "NS"

Comment: `order by buyer_num+0` this would solve the issue.

Comment: Works perfectly Abhik! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've defined `buyer_num` as string instead of integer. If you want it sorted as if it were a number, you could say

`ORDER BY CONVERT(buyer_num, SIGNED INTEGER)`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert